# Get value of a tag(<span>) for use in if/else conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a code:

```
<span id="dpos">30</span>

<script>
var pxwidth;

$( "#id" )


.bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
 pxwidth = $("#dpos").text();

 if (pxwidth === 0)
 {
 // do something
 }

});

</script>
```

Here I am trying to get the value of the span element that is used in a conditional (if/else statement). But the statement does not execute. What is the correct usage of `if (pxwidth === ?)`?

Comment: Give code that actually would run.

Comment: FYI `<span>` is a tag, not an attribute.

Comment: What is #id anyway? A form field??

Comment: #id is the id of the span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `===` to compare a string with a number.

Instead of:

```
if (pxwidth === 0)
```

Use:

```
if (pxwidth == 0) /* or */ if (pxwidth === "0")
```

`===` only returns `true` is both values are equal in value *and* type.
`$("#dpos").text()` returns a `String`,
`0` is a `Number`.
Resulting in you comparing them like this: `0 === "0"`, which is false.

**[More info on comparison operators here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)**

Answer (score 2):

There's a syntax error, you didn't close your bind function:

```
var pxwidth;

$( "#id" ).bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
    pxwidth = $("#dpos").text();

    if (pxwidth == 0) // <-- a double, not triple equal
    {
        // do something
    }
}); // <-- remember to include this
```

Also as @Cerbrus points out, you need to use the equal comparison `==` operator because you're comparing a string with an int. The triple equal `===` does an identical comparison which checks equality and data type. To demonstrate the differnece:

```
console.log( "0" == 0 ); // true
console.log( 0 == 0 ); // true
console.log( "0" === 0 ); // false
console.log( 0 === 0 ); // true
```

Comment: He's comparing `0` with `"0"`, using `===`. I believe that's the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two problems with your code:

**1. Syntax error:**

If this is all your code, you will get a syntax error. It should be visible in the console of your browser.

**2. Comparing a string with an integer:**

`.text()` returns a string, but you are trying to compare it to an integer (using triple-equality, checking the data-type as well). You will have to parse that string to an integer before doing the comparison.

Try something like this instead:

```
$(function() {
    $("#id").on("keydown", function(event) {
        var pxwidth = parseInt($("#dpos").text(), 10);

        if (pxwidth === 0)
        {
        // do something
        }
    });
});
```

**Other possible problems:**

1. You are binding to a keydown-event. Is the element with ID `id` an input-element? Otherwise there will be no way for the user to trigger the event.
2. Are you trying to bind the event before the DOM is ready? Run your code in a DOM-ready callback (see my example), or move your code to the end of your `<body>` element.

**A side note:**

`.bind()` is deprecated in favor of `.on()`, since jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine [on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Q5fB/)

```
var pxwidth = $("#dpos").text();
alert(pxwidth);
if (pxwidth === "30") {
    alert('hi');
}
```

You span has `30` in it, so checking with `0` will always return false.

### EDIT

> The `.text()` function fetches the data as a string variable. Hence, in the `if` statement, I used the `"` for comparing.

Comment: You might want to mention you also added the `""` to the `if`, otherwise, it'd still fail. (I can see it's in your answer, but people looking for an answer might overlook that)